# scrapy crash on i am try to scrape large file list urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to scrape large list urls, this is my actual variable for start_urls:

```
start_urls = [url.strip() for url in open('urls.txt','r').readlines()]
```

when i execute the crowl the system kill scrapy for missing memory, is possible do stream file on scrapy ? without load all urls on memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistake #1: `.readlines()`. File can be arbitrary large and this operation will read it entirely into memory. Since you are iterating it anyway, removing `readlines()` is absolutely safe:

`start_urls = [url.strip() for url in open('urls.txt','r')]`

Mistake #2: using list instead of an iterator. Lists are still stored completely in memory; iterators are used on demand (only one element is stored). If you don't iterate this list several times, it should be safe to change to an iterator:

`start_urls = (url.strip() for url in open('urls.txt','r'))`